# Finding divs by 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select divs with same id but to select them, like that the 1-3-5-7-9 only these divs to select.

I had tryed like that

```
$("document").ready(function(){
var c = $("#as").length;
for(var a  = 0; a<c;a--)
{

 if(c[a]%2==0){
     }
}
});
```

but it did not worked

Comment: you ned something like ':even' or ':odd' selector - like $("as:even").someOp()

Comment: No `div`s should have the same `id`, an `id` must be unique within the document.

Comment: Are you sure with `a = 0; a < c; a--`? It starts at `0`, then goes down and you check for `less than`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the odd divs with a *class* of as, not id (since you should try to only have 1 element with a given id per page), have a background color of blue do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.as:odd').css('background-color','#0000FF');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this construction:

```
$('div-selector:odd')
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have the same ID more than once in your markup. Use a class instead as IDs are supposed to be unique.

For the "every second" part you can use the :odd modifier in your selector:

```
$("#as:odd").each(function(elm){
  // Do something here with the element (elm)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To find only the odd ones:

```
$('divSelector:odd').css('background-color','#ffa');
```

Will turn all the odd-numbered `div`s selected by the selector to a yellow-background.

The divSelector could be anything from a class-name `$('.classNameOfDivs')`, or simply the element-type: `$('div')`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var c = $("#as");
    for(var a = 0; a < c; a++)
    {
        if (a % 2 == 0)
        {
            var element = c.eq(a);

            // Do stuff here.
        }
    }
});
```

A better way, however, would be to use the [`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selectors. Also note that you shouldn't have more than one element with the same `id`; use `class` instead.